# Apply color gradient to material on mesh - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex-shader, geometry-shader

I have an STL file loaded into my scene with a single colour applied to a phong material

I'd like a way of applying two colours to this mesh's material with a gradient effect applied on the Z axis a like the example below.[Gradient Vase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty9gq.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty9gq.jpg)

I have a feeling I may have to introduce shaders but I've not gotten this far with three.js.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Simple gradient shader, based on uvs:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(13, 25, 38);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
var canvas = renderer.domElement
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(2, 5, 20, 32, 1, true);
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    color1: {
      value: new THREE.Color("red")
    },
    color2: {
      value: new THREE.Color("purple")
    }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec3 color1;
    uniform vec3 color2;
  
    varying vec2 vUv;
    
    void main() {
      
      gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color1, color2, vUv.y), 1.0);
    }
  `,
  wireframe: true
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);



render();

function resize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}

function render() {
  if (resize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display;
  block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Simple gradient shader, based on coordinates:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(13, 25, 38);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
var canvas = renderer.domElement
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(2, 5, 20, 16, 4, true);
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    color1: {
      value: new THREE.Color("red")
    },
    color2: {
      value: new THREE.Color("purple")
    },
    bboxMin: {
      value: geometry.boundingBox.min
    },
    bboxMax: {
      value: geometry.boundingBox.max
    }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    uniform vec3 bboxMin;
    uniform vec3 bboxMax;
  
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
      vUv.y = (position.y - bboxMin.y) / (bboxMax.y - bboxMin.y);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec3 color1;
    uniform vec3 color2;
  
    varying vec2 vUv;
    
    void main() {
      
      gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color1, color2, vUv.y), 1.0);
    }
  `,
  wireframe: true
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);



render();

function resize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}

function render() {
  if (resize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Gradient with vertex colours:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
var canvas = renderer.domElement
document.body.appendChild(canvas);


var geom = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(2.5, .5, 100, 16);

var rev = true;

var cols = [{
  stop: 0,
  color: new THREE.Color(0xf7b000)
}, {
  stop: .25,
  color: new THREE.Color(0xdd0080)
}, {
  stop: .5,
  color: new THREE.Color(0x622b85)
}, {
  stop: .75,
  color: new THREE.Color(0x007dae)
}, {
  stop: 1,
  color: new THREE.Color(0x77c8db)
}];

setGradient(geom, cols, 'z', rev);

function setGradient(geometry, colors, axis, reverse) {

  geometry.computeBoundingBox();

  var bbox = geometry.boundingBox;
  var size = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(bbox.max, bbox.min);

  var vertexIndices = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var face, vertex, normalized = new THREE.Vector3(),
    normalizedAxis = 0;

  for (var c = 0; c < colors.length - 1; c++) {

    var colorDiff = colors[c + 1].stop - colors[c].stop;

    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
      face = geometry.faces[i];
      for (var v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
        vertex = geometry.vertices[face[vertexIndices[v]]];
        normalizedAxis = normalized.subVectors(vertex, bbox.min).divide(size)[axis];
        if (reverse) {
          normalizedAxis = 1 - normalizedAxis;
        }
        if (normalizedAxis >= colors[c].stop && normalizedAxis <= colors[c + 1].stop) {
          var localNormalizedAxis = (normalizedAxis - colors[c].stop) / colorDiff;
          face.vertexColors[v] = colors[c].color.clone().lerp(colors[c + 1].color, localNormalizedAxis);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
  wireframe: true
});
var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
scene.add(obj);



render();

function resize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}

function render() {
  if (resize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  obj.rotation.y += .01;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display;
  block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Actually, it's up to you which approach to use: shaders, vertex colours, textures etc.

Comment: Oh this is perfect, I think the gradient shader based on uvs is sufficient but I've got something to play with now and might try it out with vertex colours if I need it - thank you!!

Comment: I've tried the first method against a loader model (STL file) and it's only applying the first colour across the entire mesh.  Does this work with loader objects?

Comment: @Huskie69 If an object has uvs yes. You can pass a bounding box to the shaders and use it with coordinates of vertices of the object.

Comment: @Huskie69 I've updated the answer with the approach of using `.boundingBox` values of `.min` and `.max` in uniforms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181210/discussion-between-huskie69-and-prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849, how can we do this with 3 colors? Say from red to blue to green?

Comment: @Anye The easiest way is to use a texture with gradient.

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: Hi, your examples are very nice, but I can't apply them to single faces of a solid (BoxGeometry), how should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep the functionality of the `MeshPhongMaterial` you can try extending the material.

This is a somewhat broad topic with several approaches, and you can read more about it in depth [here](https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270).

There is a line in the phong materials shader that looks like this

```
vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );
```

So after studying the book of shaders or some other tutorials, you will learn that you can mix two colors by using a normalized factor ( a number between 0,1).

That means that you could change this line to something like this

```
vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( mix(diffuse, myColor, vec3(myFactor)), opacity);
```

You can extend the shader as such

```
const myFactor = { value: 0 }
const myColor = {value: new THREE.Color}


myMaterial.onBeforeCompile = shader=>{
  shader.uniforms.myFactor = myFactor
  shader.uniforms.myColor = myColor
  shader.fragmentShader = `
  uniform vec3 myColor;
  uniform float myFactor;
  ${shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( mix(diffuse, myColor, vec3(myFactor)), opacity);
  )}
`
```

Now when you change `myFactor.value` the color of your object should change from `myMaterial.color` to `myColor.value`.

Now to actually make it into a gradient you would replace `myFactor` with something dynamic. I like prisoners solution to use the uvs. It's entirely done in javascript, and very simple to hook up in this shader. Other approaches would probably require more shader work.

```
vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( mix(diffuse, myColor, vec3(vUv.y)), opacity);
```

Now the problem you may encounter - if you call `new PhongMaterial({color})` ie. without any textures provided to it, the shader will compile without `vUv`.
There are many conditions that would cause it to compile and be useful to you, but i'm not sure if they break other stuff:

```
#if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
```

So, adding something like

```
myMaterial.defines = {USE_MAP:''}
```

Might make `vUv` variable available for your shader. This way you get all the lights of the phong material to affect the material, you just change the base color.

Comment: I've marked the question as favourite because of your answer. Very informative.

Comment: Another fantastic and very informative answer, thank you!

Comment: `myMaterial.defines = {USE_MAP:''} ` in the latest releases (current is `r111`) they added `USE_UV:''` to enable uvs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your gradient to be static, you could just add a texture to your material using the [`.map`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.map) property. Or you could assign it to the [`.emissiveMap`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.emissiveMap) property if you want it to "glow" without the need of lights.

However, if you want your gradient to change, and always fade in the z-axis, even after rotating the model or camera, you'd have to write a custom shader, which would require you to take some tutorials. You could look at [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shader.html) for how to implement custom shaders in Three.js, and visit https://thebookofshaders.com/ to get a good understanding on how to write a simple gradient shader.