# How to best represent graded lenses?

Tags: three.js

How would I go about creating a material in three.js that best represent graded lenses of this type exemplified below?

[image]

What is the best practice: to vary the opacity for a gradient (which wouldnt be enough on its own), to vary the emissive map, or to vary the map property of the material.

Seems like if opacity were not varied in addition to varying either the map or emissive map, since the glasses do let less light at the top, some of the physical reality of the representation would be uncaptured by the 3D model.

Is there another way that I'm not considering? Maybe a type of material class that is best suited for the job?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`MeshPhysicalMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhysicalMaterial), which has the benefit of allowing for two layers:

1. The base color that could fade to transparent.
2. A clear coat on top that shows reflections.

What you'd need to do is set the `.clearcoat` property to max (1). Then take a gradient texture that fades from red to black and assign it to [`.transmissionMap`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhysicalMaterial.transmissionMap) (transmissionMap only reads the red channel)

See [this demo in their examples page](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_physical_transmission), when transmission is 1, the shapes are opaque. When transmission is 0, the shapes are transparent, but still maintain their reflections.